# List View Android App

Tags: java, android, xml, android-listview

I need android list view project with following details:

- should contain 10 rows and should show only 3 rows at a time,
- should have up and down arrows to it which moves rows up or down to view ,
- if it is top of list up arrow should disabled and its bottom of list down arrow should disabled.

Any one please help me and make this code thanks in advance

Comment: try this one right here make this as a sample reference maybe it can help this one is from "Omar" http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/y3yfE/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a `ListView` with 3 rows you'll need to have a custom adapter and override it's `getView()` method. You can inflate a layout with 2 buttons here and add `OnClickListener` to both of them. Your `OnClickListener` must override `onClick()` method whose body must be something like below:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    int currentIndex = listView.indexOfChild(v.getParent());
    View view = listView.getChildAt(currentIndex);
    switch(id) {
    case upButtonId:
        listView.removeView(view);
        listView.addView(view, currentIndex--);
        if(currentIndex == 0)
            //disable Up Button
        break;
    case downButtonId:
        listView.removeView(view);
        listView.addView(view, currentIndex++);
        if(currentIndex == listView.getChildCount() - 1)
            //disable Down Button
        break;
    }
}
```